# What are the differences between the Handlebars 1.x and 2.x APIs?

Tags: handlebars.js, compatibility

We are currently using Handlebars version 1.3.0 in production, and I'd like to know what, if anything, we'll need to change in order to be able to upgrade to version 2.x. Since the HandlebarsJS team is committed to semantic versioning I know there must be some breaking changes, but I don't see them listed in the [README.md](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/README.markdown). There are some items listed in the [changelogs for the v2.0.0-alpha.N releases](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md#v200-alpha1---february-10th-2014), but it's not clear to me whether or not this is a complete list (or if a complete list would even exist before 2.0.0 final is released). Some of the 1.x releases have "compatibilty notse" sections as well, but I believe they are all non-breaking/forward-compatible.

Could anyone offer some insight into the API differences or the goals/improvements of the 2.x series?

> ### Compatiblity Notes
>
> - A JSON polyfill is required to run the compiler under IE8 and below. It's recommended that the precompiler be used in lieu of running the compiler on these legacy environments.
>
>   ---
> - `helperMissing` helper no longer has the indexed name argument. Helper name is now available via options.name.
> - Precompiler output has changed, which breaks compatibility with prior versions of the runtime and precompiled output.
> - `JavaScriptCompiler.compilerInfo` now returns generic objects rather than javascript source.
> - AST changes
>
>   - INTEGER -> NUMBER
>   - Additional PartialNode hash parameter
>   - New RawBlockNode type
> - Data frames now have a _parent field. This is internal but is enumerable for performance/compatability reasons.

### Update: From the [ember.js blog](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html) on 10/16/2014

In addition to the changes noted above:

> Lines containing only block statements and whitespace are now removed. 
>     This matches the Mustache spec but may cause issues with code that expects
>     whitespace to exist but would not otherwise.

Comment: I think the most major changes was in the precompiler. You can not use templates precompiled with 1.x version of Handlebars on 2.x runtime. If you are using precompiled templates on client, you should update your backend environment, runtime library and recompile all the templates. If you used Handlebars only on browser, you can simply update library, it shouldn't break anything, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So the key item is: "Precompiler output has changed, which breaks compatibility with prior versions of the runtime and precompiled output." If someone will post that as an answer I will accept it if nothing better / more authoritative comes along in the next week.

Comment: I've recently moved my project from Handlebars 1.x to 2.x, but my templates were almost straight and simple, without any special techniques used. I think here should be written more complex answer, because changes like "_Access to root context in partials and helpers_" can really break someone's templates. I'll try to write complete answer describing all changes soon.

Comment: My handlebars is breaking in IE8 and lower by outputting [string string] wherever it should be outputting any actual content. I assume that's related to the JSON polyfill, however I dont know what it's talking about since it doesn't actually provide the polyfill. Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @dudewad, you'll have much better luck getting an answer if you create a separate question for that (this one is different and is already answered). I would also highly recommend creating a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your problem. It might even end up needing to be filed on [the handlebars issue tracker](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at changes between v1.3.0 and v2.0.0-alpha.1 releases of Handlebars accordingly to official [Release Notes](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md#v200-alpha1---february-10th-2014) you will see, that was two major changes, that would break your templates during upgrade.

1. Precompiler output has changed, which means your 1.x precompiled templates would not be compatible with Handlebars 2.x runtime, as well as 2.x runtime will be not compatible with old templates. You should update precompiler, update runtime and update all templates.
2. Partials no longer have access to parent context (`../`), but now can accept hash as argument and has access to the root context through `@root` variable. So look at your partials for using `../` and change it to using local data, passed to partial as argument.

So, that's the main things you should pay attention when upgrading to 2.x Handlebars version. There was some internal changes which affect `helperMissing` helper, `JavaScriptCompiler.compilerInfo`, updates **AST** and **data frames**. But all of that makes sense only for users, who uses their own forks or making some of the modifications in runtime. Other changes was primarily bugfixes.

Comment: I would like to clarify that the `../` concern applies to root level instances of `../` only. I.e. you can access within different contexts in the same partial but you can not access the data that executed the partial directly. I.e.

    {{foo}}
    {{#with bar}}
      {{../foo}}
    {{/with}}


Would be completely valid as a partial and would print the value of `foo` twice.

    {{../foo}}


Would be an invalid partial though.